# Full width browser help. before I pull all my hair out

Tags: css, muse

Basically I'm very very new to .css and HTML and I have been using Adobe Muse or word press to make sites and have been able to get by. Well I have been integrating a shopping cart system called Foxycart into one of my sites and I can not for the life of me get the header, shadow under the header and middle image (repeating pattern) to stretch across the screen. Adobe muse does this by using JavaScript, but when I cache my template for Foxycart the JavaScript no longer works. Which is fine I would like to use .css to stretch the header and middle background anyway. The problem is I can not figure it out. I hate to ask for help but I have spent over two days trying to figure it out and still not luck. I specialize in graphics, so if anyone that helps me out needs anything photoshop'd or what not just let me know. For my own sanity to need to figure this out!

Code is cached by Foxycart located here: https://shavemate.foxycart.com/checkout.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You should have titled the question "Full width browser help. Before the question is closed out" :)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers add padding around the viewport, so in order to get a true "full width" effect you need to make your header have a `absolute` position along with `top:0; left: 0`. The tricky thing here in my experience is getting the width to 100%. With an absolute positioned element, 100% width seems to go off the right side of the screen. It may have to be done with javascript or someone here with more mastery of CSS can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

in site properties, layout you can make margins 0,0,0,0

Also, if you want something to be 100% width just snap the edges to each side of page browser.

hope this help.

yd.